# How to create search form from multiple tables cakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, associations, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

In this issue I have 2 tables involved: jobs and areas.

I'm trying to create a **search element** which will be available on all views and contain a textfield for filtering rows by jobs title or jobs description and a droplist for filtering rows by areas and I want them to all work together.

So I created a search function on JobsController:

```
public function search()
{
    if($this->request->data('area_select') != 'select area') {
        $jobs = $this->Jobs
            ->find('all')
            ->contain(['Types', 'Categories' => function($q) {
                return $q
                    ->where([
                        'Jobs.title OR Jobs.description LIKE' =>
                            "%" . $this->request->data('keywords') . "%"
                    ])
                    ->where([
                        'Jobs.area LIKE' =>
                            "%" . $this->request->data('area_select') ."%"
                    ]);
                }]
            );
    } else {
        $jobs = $this->Jobs
            ->find('all')
            ->contain(['Categories' => function($q) {
                return $q->where([
                    'Jobs.title OR Jobs.description LIKE' =>
                        "%" . $this->request->data('keywords') . "%"
                ]);
            }]
        );
    }

    $this->set('jobs',$jobs);
}
```

it works good if I'm approaching to areas via jobs

```
<?php foreach($jobs as $job): ?>
    <option><?php echo $job->area->name; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the problem is that by accessing through jobs table it repeats the the same area as many times as the it appears in jobs table instead of only once...

so if I'm trying to get direct access like this:

```
<?php foreach($areas as $area): ?>
    <option><?php echo $area->name; ?></option>         
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

it is not working because I'm submitted to jobs controller.
How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Your conditions look wrong, you shouldn't create such SQL snippets on the `key` side, also applying them in the `Categories` containment could only work if that were a `hasOne` or `belongsTo` association, but even then you shouldn't apply them there, but on `Jobs` level instead. That being said, it's hard to follow what you're describing, it sounds like your missing some grouping somewhere, or maybe your query approach is wrong in the first place. Please add a little more context, starting with the exact data sture that you need to retrieve.

Comment: Ok, actually the search function is working perfectlly, it retrive exactly what i need. I shouldn't to display that snnipet in the first place because its not the problem, so sorry for the confusion. all i want is that the search element `$this->element('search')` wich contain droplist of areas will be able to retrive data from the areas table directly instead through jobs table because if i retriving by the second way it cause duplication of areas in the list. and you right, jobs belongsTo areas.